# Failed to execute user defined function when aggregating in a dataframe groupby user

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe as below ,I am trying to get the max(sum) for the user groupby name.

```
+-----+-----------------------------+
|name |nt_set                       |
+-----+-----------------------------+
|Bob  |[av:27.0, bcd:29.0, abc:25.0]|
|Alice|[abc:95.0, bcd:55.0]         |
|Bob  |[abc:95.0, bcd:70.0]         |
|Alice|[abc:125.0, bcd:90.0]        |
+-----+-----------------------------+
```

Below is the udf I am using to get the max(sum) for the user

```
val maxfunc = udf((arr: Array[String]) => {
val step1 = arr.map(x => (x.split(":", -1)(0), x.split(":", -1)(1))).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(arr => arr.map(_._2.toInt).sum).maxBy(_._2)
val result = step1._1 + ":" + step1._2
result})
```

And when I run the udf,Its throwing the below error

```
 val c6 = c5.withColumn("max_nt", maxfunc(col("nt_set"))).show(false)
```

> Error: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array) =>string)

How do I achieve this in a better performed way because I need to do this in a larger dataset

The expected result is

```
expected result:
+-----+-----------------------------+
|name |max_nt                       |
+-----+-----------------------------+
|Bob  |abc:120.0                    |
|Alice|abc:220.0                    |
+-----+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core logic of your `maxfunc` works correctly except that it should handle a post-groupBy array-column, which is a nested `Seq` collection:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Bob", Seq("av:27.0", "bcd:29.0", "abc:25.0")),
  ("Alice", Seq("abc:95.0", "bcd:55.0")),
  ("Zack", Seq()),
  ("Bob", Seq("abc:50.0", null)),
  ("Bob", Seq("abc:95.0", "bcd:70.0")),
  ("Alice", Seq("abc:125.0", "bcd:90.0"))
).toDF("name", "nt_set")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val maxfunc = udf( (ss: Seq[Seq[String]]) => {
  val groupedSeq: Map[String, Double] = ss.flatMap(identity).
    collect{ case x if x != null => (x.split(":")(0), x.split(":")(1)) }.
    groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2.toDouble).sum)

  groupedSeq match {
    case x if x == Map.empty[String, Double] => ("", -999.0)
    case _ => groupedSeq.maxBy(_._2)
  }
} )

df.groupBy("name").agg(collect_list("nt_set").as("arr_nt")).
  withColumn("max_nt", maxfunc($"arr_nt")).
  select($"name", $"max_nt._1".as("max_key"), $"max_nt._2".as("max_val")).
  show
// +-----+-------+-------+
// | name|max_key|max_val|
// +-----+-------+-------+
// | Zack|       | -999.0|
// |  Bob|    abc|  170.0|
// |Alice|    abc|  220.0|
// +-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: can we divide that abc,120 to two separate columns? If yes please update the answer.Thanks greatly appreciate it

Comment: @Babu, please see my expanded answer.

Comment: just one thing,its not handling the null or empty values if there are any

Comment: Empty list in `nt_set` would be fine.  As for null elements in `nt_set`, I've updated the `udf` to use Scala's `collect` method to handle them.  See updated answer with additional test data.

Comment: But I get this error==>Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.maxBy

Comment: That would happen in case all `nt_set` associated with a given `name` is empty.  Please see updated answer.  It's worth noting that if you need a solution that handles certain specific cases, it'll help by providing sample data that covers those cases in your question.

Comment: Thanks Leo,sorry ,Its a large data set,I am getting to know the issue once I run it. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of what you are trying to do, your example is wrong. Alice's bcd fields only sum to 145 whereas her abc fields sum to 220. So abc should be selected for her as well. If I am wrong, then I misunderstood your problem.

Anyway, you don't need a udf to do what you want. Let's generate your data:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("Bob", Array("av:27.0", "bcd:29.0", "abc:25.0")), 
    ("Alice", Array("abc:95.0", "bcd:55.0")), 
    ("Bob", Array("abc:95.0", "bcd:70.0")), 
    ("Alice", Array("abc:125.0", "bcd:90.0"))) )
        .toDF("name", "nt_set")
```

Then, one way to go is to explode nt_set into a column nt that only contains one string/value pair.

```
df.withColumn("nt", explode('nt_set))
  //then we split the string and the value
  .withColumn("nt_string", split('nt, ":")(0))
  .withColumn("nt_value", split('nt, ":")(1).cast("int"))
  //then we sum the values by name and "string"
  .groupBy("name", "nt_string")
  .agg(sum('nt_value) as "nt_value")
  /* then we build a struct with the value first to be able to select
     the nt field with max value while keeping the corresponding string */
  .withColumn("nt", struct('nt_value, 'nt_string))
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg(max('nt) as "nt")
  // And we rebuild the "nt" column.
  .withColumn("max_nt", concat_ws(":", $"nt.nt_string", $"nt.nt_value"))
  .drop("nt").show(false)

+-----+-------+
|name |max_nt |
+-----+-------+
|Bob  |abc:120|
|Alice|abc:220|
+-----+-------+
```

Comment: sorry there was a small mistake in the question which I corrected,and yeah your solution works but I think its expensive as I have to do it for each name for large dataset. I looking for anything precise for better performance like using udf

Comment: Using a udf won't necessarily better performance. It is even generally the other way around. The difference between Leo's answer is that he starts with a group by. If a name cannot occur too many times, it is going to be better than my solution. If some names occur a lot though, Leo's solution might yield an out of memory error because all the fields of that name will have to be in one single row. By exploding the dataframe and then using simple group by and sums, I avoid this issue. Yet you are right, exploding a dataframe can be expensive.